# Experiencing the below mentioned crash on Nexus 5 (Android 5.0.1)

Tags: android

Experiencing the below mentioned crash on Nexus 5 (Android 5.0.1) but my apk is working on other Android version including 5.0.2. We are experiencing at the facebook login for the first time only which is also on Nexus 5.0.1. Any idea?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:     Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.flushAndWait(AppEventsLogger.java:761)
at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.access$1(AppEventsLogger.java:733)
at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger$2.run(AppEventsLogger.java:605)
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.base.cricketduniya-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
... 4 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: The solution was to add latest facebook library.